# jQuery counter at start up to load page fully

Tags: javascript, jquery

Which plugin or snippet I can use to put on beginning of the page and wait to disappear  after page all element has been loaded?

Here is an example of the function which I am talking about:

[Example](http://www.betacollective.ca/)

Comment: "All elements" is a bit vague requirement. This particular page for example is dynamically updated with comments, so it's unlikely it to be loaded completely in next few minutes.

Comment: In Next few Minutes?!

Comment: you've just proven it. One of page elements was loaded 3 minutes after the page was created. So keeping in mind these days apps update pages dynamically, what does "all elements" mean?

Comment: I mean document element, for example if I have a slider with some large images , I need some one to cover the page untill all of these lazy loaded been loaded!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on your webpage structure if that is something like this:

```
<body>
   <div id="wrapper">
       <!--The other content of the page here-->
   </div>
</body>
```

then you can do this:

In css:

```
#wrapper{ display:none; } // hide everything
```

then in the js:

```
document.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
   document.querySelector("#wrapper").style.display = "block";
});
```

### Note:

This is just for static content of the page only. Any async js code will not be affected with this code.